# Making a function with Options, where the option depends on the function variables

Tags: functions, options

Lets say as a (dumb) minimal example you had the following:

```
Options[my$plot] = {"SetColor" -> (*...don't know how to do this...*)};

my$plot[x_,OptionsPattern[]]:=Table[{OptionValue["SetColor"][[i]], Sphere[x[[i]]]},
 {i,1,Length@x}]
```

and I want to have a default set of colors if not provided, lets say:

```
(*default of "SetColors" something like:*) Table[Hue[i/Length@x],{i,0,Length@x}]
```

How can you achieve such behaviour?

Comment: Make the option into a function that depends on the arg or on the index, e.g. `"SetColor"->ColorData[97]` and then `MapIndexed[{OptionValue["SetColor"][#2[[1]]], Sphere[#]}&, x]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally one uses `Automatic` as the default option setting, then computes the actual value within the function.

```
Options[my$plot] = {"SetColor" -> Automatic};

my$plot[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 With[{setcolor = 
         Replace[
           OptionValue["SetColor"], 
           Automatic :> Table[Hue[i/Length@x], {i, 0, Length@x}]]
      },
  Table[{setcolor[[i]], Sphere[x[[i]]]}, {i, 1, Length@x}]
 ]
```

Comment: Did not know about `Automatic`. Very helpful.

Comment: @Pana `Automatic` doesn't really do anything here. It could be any other expression in principle. It is merely a convention that when the default option value is computed automatically based on something else, we use `Automatic`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I realised this later when I used this in my actual notebook, and was thinking using specifically `Automatic` must be a convention for clarity among different users.